# Is it possible to sort objects by two fields both in reversed natural order using a Comparator.comparingInt chain

Tags: java, java-8, reverse, comparator, method-chaining

Lets say I want to sort objects in an `ArrayList` on a field `height` in reversed order and if two values are the same I want to further sort on the field width also in reversed order.
Is there a way by using something like

```
 Comparator<Test> comparator = Comparator
            .comparingInt((Test t) -> t.height).reversed()
            .thenComparingInt((Test t ) -> t.width).reversed();
```

I know I could use something like:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Test>() {

        public int compare(Test o1, Test o2) {

            Integer x1 =  o1.height;
            Integer x2 =  o2.height;
            int sComp = x2.compareTo(x1);

            if (sComp != 0) {
                return sComp;
            }

            x1 = o1.width;
            x2 = o2.width;
            return x2.compareTo(x1);
        }});
```

But I'm really curious if there is one line solution

So regarding this mini-example

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test one = new Test();
        one.height = 2;
        one.width = 1;
        Test two = new Test();
        two.height = 2;
        two.width = 3;
        Test three = new Test();
        three.height = 1;
        three.width = 1;

        Comparator<Test> comparator = Comparator
            .comparingInt((Test t) -> t.height).reversed()
            .thenComparingInt((Test t ) -> t.width).reversed();

        List<Test> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(one);
        list.add(two);
        list.add(three);

        list.stream()
            .sorted(comparator)
            .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.height + "/" + e.width));
    }
}

class Test {
    int width;
    int height;
}
```

I get the output:

```
1/1
2/3
2/1
```

because the second `reversed()` reverses the whole list. 
Is there a way to gean a output of:

```
2/3
2/1
1/1
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

just remove `reversed()` from `comparingInt` and only call `reversed` upon `thenComparingLong`:

```
Comparator<Test> comparator = 
      Comparator.comparingInt((Test t) -> t.height) // <--- removed reverse from this comparator
                .thenComparingLong((Test t ) -> t.width).reversed();
```

Further, given that `width` is an `int` I'd use `thenComparingInt` instead of `thenComparingLong`.

In addition, in regard to your stream pipeline, I'd suggest using `forEachOrdered` since **you care about the order** in which the elements are printed.

`forEach` is documented as:

> The behavior of this operation is explicitly nondeterministic. For
>   parallel stream pipelines, this operation does not guarantee to
>   respect the encounter order of the stream, as doing so would sacrifice
>   the benefit of parallelism.

Therefore:

```
 list.stream()
     .sorted(comparator)
     .forEachOrdered(e -> System.out.println(e.height + "/" + e.width));
```

Comment: Okay thanks that seems to be right. The long part was an error in the example. Would this also work on a longer chain, if not all parts are in the same sortOrder?

Answer (score 5):

To complete the very good answer of Aomine I will expose the possibilities and the behavior behind them.
Note that you should favor getters (and also method references) over direct field access.   So I will illustrate with that. 
I will also rely on `static import` for `Comparator` static methods such as     `import static java.util.Comparator.*;` to focus on important things.

What you do actually cancels the initial reversed `Comparator` on `getHeight()`:

```
Comparator<Test> comparator = 
       comparingInt(Test::getHeight)
       .reversed() // 1)
       .thenComparingInt(Test::getWidth) // 2)
       .reversed(); // 3)
```

In terms of logic it means :

1) Sort by comparing on the reverse of `Test::getHeight`.
2) Then sort by comparing on `Test::getWidth`.
3) Reverse the whole comparing logic.

So you get a Comparator that sorts on `Test::getHeight` and 
then sorts on the reverse of `Test::getWidth`.

In the solution provided by Aomine :

```
Comparator<Test> comparator = 
       comparingInt(Test::getHeight) // 1)
       .thenComparingInt(Test::getWidth) // 2)
       .reversed(); // 3)
```

In terms of logic it means :

1) Sort by comparing on `Test::getHeight`.
2) Then sort by comparing on `Test::getWidth`.
3) Reverse the whole comparing logic.

So you get a Comparator that sorts on the reverse of `Test::getHeight` and 
then sorts on the reverse of `Test::getWidth`.

You could also write the code in this way (while more verbose but interesting in terms of learning) :

```
Comparator<Test> comparator = 
       comparingInt(Test::getHeight) 
       .reversed() // 1)
       .thenComparing(comparingInt(Test::getWidth)
                      .reversed()); // 2)
```

In terms of logic it means :

1) Sort by comparing on the reverse of `Test::getHeight`.
2) Then sort by comparing on the reverse of `Test::getWidth`.

That produces still a Comparator that sorts on the reverse of `Test::getHeight` and 
then sorts on the reverse of `Test::getWidth`.